# Ctrl+Tab switch across all open tabs - is this impossible?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am looking for switching across all open tabs like in for example IntelliJ IDEA - seems like it's the most convenient way but from what I see it's impossible in VS Code and I can't believe that.

I see only possibilities to switch only in current split/editor or switch through recently opened (but then instead of switching to already open tab in different split it opens it in the active split duplicating it - what the hell).

Is VS Code really lacking such a simple functionality?

Maybe is there some extension for this? I haven't found any.

Edit: Well, I have also found this:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+tab", "command": "workbench.action.showAllEditors" }
```

But it doesn't show them by recent like other editors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on mac and the default is <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd> +<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>, or
<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to jump back to previous tab or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to jump tabs also works.

if you are using windows, I'm not sure what the equivalent is however you can customize your own shortcuts, in your VSCode go to `Code > Preferences > keyboard shortcuts` and search for:

`workbench.action.previousEditor` -> to jump to previous tab

`workbench.action.nextEditor` -> to jump to next tab

and bind your desired key combination, this may or may not override existing shortcuts.

this will also jump to the next/previous tab if you have split editor.

Hope this helps!